# vb.net can't upload my file in google drive

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, google-docs-api

i'm using google drive api for upload a pdf file (with vb.net) , i searched a many tutorial in this and another website (how to get google drive api in vb.net , how to upload ...) and finally i have sucessfully done it
but the problem , No files are added in drive

here is my code

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    Dim filename As String = fichier.FileName 'from selected file in openfiledialog
    CreateService()
    UploadFile(filename)
End Sub


Private Service As DriveService = New DriveService

Private Sub CreateService()

    Dim ClientId = "*********"
    Dim ClientSecret = "****************"
    Dim MyUserCredential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = ClientId, .ClientSecret = ClientSecret}, {DriveService.Scope.Drive}, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result
    Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential, .ApplicationName = "Google Drive VB Dot Net"})
End Sub
Private Sub UploadFile(FilePath As String)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    CreateService()
    Dim ByteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
    Dim Stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MsgBox("Upload Finished")
End Sub
```

when i execute my application , the result is

[image]

but i can't found any file in drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling CreateService() twice but never use it to upload anything.

```
Private Sub UploadFile(FilePath As String)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    CreateService()
    Dim ByteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
    Dim Stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)
    '' ---------------------------------------------------------
    '' Here you'll going to use the service to upload your data
    '' with Service.Files.Create()
    '' ---------------------------------------------------------
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MsgBox("Upload Finished")
End Sub
```

Comment: insert is not a member of fileresource

Comment: Fixed, was v2 API with v3 you'll use Files.Create()

Comment: i'm stuck , how i use it (give me an example )

Comment: I used v2 API and i add 
Dim TheFile As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()

            TheFile.Title = "My document"
            TheFile.Description = " document"
            TheFile.MimeType = "text/plain"

            Dim Up As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = Service.Files.Insert(TheFile, Stream, TheFile.MimeType)

but the same result

Comment: I found a solution , i add this : up.upload() and the result is done , but when i want to see the file , i can't because the file is crypted